# How to specify formula with dataframe columns that are named with numeric strings

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to loop through my dataframe to check for the best predictor of an outcome. The column names of my dataframe are numeric (0.1, 0.2). The formula function does not work when running a model, such as a glm, with the predictor as a numeric value.

```
formula_string <- "outcome~0.1"
test_formula <- formula(formula_string)
GLM <- glm(test_formula, data=df)
```

I want it to run, but instead i get the error:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may need backquotes to evaluate the column name as such

```
formula_string <- "outcome~`0.1`"
```